# How do I parse a state variable's value into a <Link> element's target url in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, react-router

I have been trying to call the profile link using a state variable id, to navigate to a specific user's profile, the method below doesn't work but if I am able to put the 'id' value into the url as I am trying to do below it will work because in App.js:

```
<Route path="/user/:id" component={Profile} />
```

And I need the link below to be clickable on the home page to take a logged in user to their profile by fetching their id from the server and saving it in a state variable and then parsing the value into the url dynamically.
Home.js:

```
 constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            id: localStorage.getItem("id");
        }
    
        componentDidMount() {
            const payload = {
                "username": localStorage.getItem("username")
            };
    
            fetch(ID_FROM_USERNAME_URL, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": localStorage.getItem("token"),
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(payload)
            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    console.log("id from server:")
                    console.log(data);
                    localStorage.setItem("id", data);
                });
        }

In render() return ()

    <Button color=

"link"><Link to="/user/${this.state.id}">Profile</Link></Button>`
```

How can I parse the state variable's value into this Link element?

Thanks

Comment: You've a typo in forming the link target. When using string templates use backtick (`\``) characters. `to="/user/${this.state.id}"` should be `to=\`/user/${this.state.id}\``.

Answer (score 1):

you are using template literal wrong.. it need to be passed as variable and in backticks

`` <Link to={`/user/${this.state.id}`}>Profile</Link></Button> ``

Answer (score 1):

You need to use template literal, it's a nice feature added in ES6.

```
<Link to={`/user/${this.state.id}`}>Profile</Link></Button>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Also, it looks like your code is broken, you don't have state and setState and it's not wise to use storage for this task.

Comment: hey, I was wondering why it's not good to use storage? After changing the link to what you two have responded with I realised it did not work, so I had to use {localStorage.getItem("id"); Is there anything wrong with that? thanks

Comment: Yes, the better approach is using `useState`. Also, it looks like you haven't gone through any docs or tutorial, before starting to code in `react`. I highly recommend that, In 4-5 hours crash course. you would be good to start coding, as you already have the fundamentals. :)